Error building workspace of MoveIt 2 (Jazzy Jalisco)
By following the steps listed in https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html, I get the following error when executing the command “colcon build --mixin release”:
    Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_description
Starting >>> object_recognition_msgs
Starting >>> moveit_common
Starting >>> moveit_resources_pr2_description
Starting >>> moveit_configs_utils
Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_description
Starting >>> moveit_resources_prbt_support
Starting >>> robotiq_description
--- stderr: object_recognition_msgs   
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Failed   <<< object_recognition_msgs [0.39s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< moveit_common [0.39s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_resources_panda_description [0.40s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_resources_pr2_description [0.39s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_description [0.38s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_resources_prbt_support [0.38s]
Aborted  <<< robotiq_description [0.38s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_configs_utils [1.20s]                      

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.62s]
  1 package failed: object_recognition_msgs
  7 packages aborted: moveit_common moveit_configs_utils moveit_resources_fanuc_description moveit_resources_panda_description moveit_resources_pr2_description moveit_resources_prbt_support robotiq_description
  1 package had stderr output: object_recognition_msgs
  64 packages not processed

Thank you in advance.

It looks like you imported the ROS1 version of object_recognition_msgs.
Did you specify the correct branch in the following install step? main should be the best option.

cd ~/ws_moveit/src
git clone -b <branch> https://github.com/moveit/moveit2_tutorials


If so, you could remove and clone the package manually into your workspace from:
https://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_msgs/tree/ros2
The same counts here, use the correct branch:
git clone -b ros2 https://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_msgs.git


Edit
After some searching, moveit2_tutorials does not have a dedicated ROS2 Jazzy branch yet. moveit2 does but if you're learning from scratch, I'd recommend starting with ROS2 Humble and upgrading to Jazzy then you've got the basics down.

I'll install ROS2 Humble. Thank you very much!
